# How to fetch a one table from HTML source file using lwp module?

Tags: perl, lwp

I'm beginner. I want to know how to fetch one table form the source HTML file using LWP module? Is it possible to use Regex with LWP?

Comment: You can combine all kinds of things, that's what programming is all about. But your question does not make much sense. It is way too broad. If you want to extract data from a website, you should not use plain regex, but an HTML parser instead. LWP is for fetching the website off the internet. Then a parser to make sense of the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LWP to get the HTML source of a web page. Most easily, by using the `get()` function from [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple).

```
my $html = get('http://example.com/');
```

Now, in `$html` you have a text string (potentially a very long text string) which contains HTML. You can use any techniques you want to extract data from that string.

(**Hint:** Using a regex to do this is likely to be a very bad idea. It will be far harder than you expect and probably very fragile. Perhaps use a better tool - like [HTML::TableExtract](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TableExtract) instead.)

Answer (score 0):

```
use Web::Query::LibXML 'wq';

wq('https://www.december.com/html/demo/table.html')
    ->find('table th')
    ->each(sub {
        my (undef, $e) = @_;
        print $e->text . "\n";
    });
__END__
Outer Table
Inner Table
CORNER
Head1
Head2
Head3
Head4
Head5
Head6
Little
```